# DotNetNuke : How to secure ASP page (separately developed)

Tags: vb.net, security, asp-classic, dotnetnuke

I have an issue with the DotNetNuke CMS, it is as follows:

- There is a VB ASP file that is publicly accessible by URL.
- This file is contained in a folder and it is not developed according the dnn concept. It is separately developed.

I want to secure access into this file to ADMIN group. Can i do that through the DNN Interface?

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is create a custom module for the DNN and deploy it. [Click here](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/module-development) to get resource about module development.

But in your case, There are asp.net pages separately, This is the heck for this.
Check in asp.net page load event whether user has a particular role or not, based on that you can redirect a user to other page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var currentUser = UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo();
    if (!currentUser.IsInRole("Administrators"))
    {
        //Redirect to some other page
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Mr. Gajendra, the developed asp page has asp extention (*.asp) it is basic asp & not asp.net; is that is valid for this case?